# Excel VBA to Scrape CSS Siblings

Tags: html, css, excel, vba, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape data from a group of webpages like this one: https://www.cookcountyassessor.com/pin/14333230200000/print

Much of the data seems to referenced by a single CSS Class with multiple siblings named "detail-row--detail" (with the data labels being contained in "detail-row--label").  So the first data item is contained in detail-row--detail:eq(0), the second in detail-row--detail:eq(1), etc.  My VBA will grab the first detail-row--detail, but not any subsequent items.

See below for a simplified snippet of my code.  The cell TargetURL contains the URL above.  The range CSSRange contains 3 values: "print-pint", "address", & "detail-row--detail" (all without the quotes).  The MsgBox (which is only there for testing purposes) correctly returns the values for the first 2 CSSRange items (which do not have multiple siblings).  For the 3rd CSS item (which has 31 siblings), it runs through the For-Each loop the correct number of times, but each time returns the value of the first sibling.  Any suggestions as to how I might scrape the value of each subsequent sibling?

```
Sub SnippetForStackOverflow()
'Be sure to load Tools > References "Microsoft Internet Controls" & "Microsoft HTML Object Library"

Dim ShtSource As Worksheet
Dim CSSRange As Range
Dim TargetURL As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim n As Integer
Dim webpage As HTMLDocument
Dim element As IHTMLElement
Dim Output As String
Dim ie As InternetExplorer

'Get things ready
    Set ShtSource = Sheets("PINforVBA")
    Set TargetURL = ShtSource.Range("$B$2")
    Set CSSRange = ShtSource.Range("$B$5:$B$7")

'Open IE in memory, go to site
    Set ie = New InternetExplorer
    ie.Visible = True 'SET AS FALSE UNLESS DEBUGGING
    ie.navigate (TargetURL.Value)
    Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        Application.StatusBar = "Loading Web page …"
        DoEvents
    Loop
    Set webpage = ie.document

'Scrape desired elements
    For Each rng In CSSRange
        For Each element In webpage.getElementsByClassName(rng.Value)
            n = n + 1
            Output = webpage.getElementsByClassName(rng.Value)(0).innerText
            MsgBox (n & ": " & Output)
        Next
        n = 0
    Next

'Wrap it up
    ie.Quit
    Set ie = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: create an array, do a split(), cycle through the result and return the details you want.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Mech.  I am a bit of a VBA newb.  Can you give me some direction on how to implement that?

Comment: what specifically are you trying to extract?

Comment: I am trying to extract all the data items on the page.  My code works to grab data items where there is only 1 item with a given CSS name.  But there are 31 data items named detail-row--detail, and instead of returning those 31 items, my code returns the first one 31 times.

Comment: Here is an example of the HTML for 2 of the 31 data items named "detail-row--detail":

Comment: `<div class="detail-row">`
`    <span class="detail-row--label">Property Classification</span>`
`    <span class="detail-row--detail">206</span>`
`</div>`
`<div class="detail-row">`
`    <span class="detail-row--label">Square Footage (Land)</span>`
`    <span class="detail-row--detail">2,275</span>`
`</div>`

Comment: Try changing this portion in your code from `Output = webpage.getElementsByClassName()` to `Output = element.getElementsByClassName()`.

Comment: Almost like SIM wrote it. But to make it work you have to replace `Output = webpage.getElementsByClassName(rng.Value)(0).innerText` with `Output = element.innerText`. The single element already exists. It cannot be identified again.

Comment: SIM and Zwenn, thanks a million!  The code revision from @Zwenn did the trick.  Appreciate the help!

Comment: At the risk of asking an even more basic question, is there a way to mark the comment from @Zwenn as the answer?  If not, Zwenn, if you post as a proposed answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have commented what I have done in the code. Include reseting the status bar.

```
Sub SnippetForStackOverflow()
'Be sure to load Tools > References "Microsoft Internet Controls" & "Microsoft HTML Object Library"

Dim ShtSource As Worksheet
Dim CSSRange As Range
Dim TargetURL As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim n As Integer
Dim webpage As HTMLDocument
Dim element As IHTMLElement
Dim Output As String
Dim ie As InternetExplorer

  'Get things ready
  Set ShtSource = Sheets("PINforVBA")
  Set TargetURL = ShtSource.Range("$B$2")
  Set CSSRange = ShtSource.Range("$B$5:$B$7")
  
  'Open IE in memory, go to site
  Set ie = New InternetExplorer
  ie.Visible = True 'SET AS FALSE UNLESS DEBUGGING
  ie.navigate (TargetURL.Value)
  Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Application.StatusBar = "Loading Web page …"
    DoEvents
  Loop
  Set webpage = ie.document
  
  'Scrape desired elements
  For Each rng In CSSRange
    For Each element In webpage.getElementsByClassName(rng.Value)
      n = n + 1
      
      'The following line searches in the whole document
      'That's the reason, why always the first Element was listed
      'Output = webpage.getElementsByClassName(rng.Value)(0).innerText
      
      'Some changes in the code will do what is wanted
      Output = element.innerText
      MsgBox (n & ": " & Output)
    Next
    n = 0
  Next
  
  'Wrap it up
  ie.Quit
  Set ie = Nothing
  
  'Reset status bar
  Application.StatusBar = False
End Sub
```